# Why does Survivalist lie down outside after getting wounded?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-survivalist

In the Survivalist movie, the main protagonist gets shot in the abdomen. Then after the bullet is removed and his wound is cauterised, he goes outside and lies down on the ground and lifts up some sheet.
[image]

Why does he lie down on the ground and what is that sheet he's lifting up?

I'm asking because afterward, they show worms crawling out of his wound. What exactly was he trying to do?

Comment: i am interested to know the answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [script](https://8flix.com/assets/screenplays/b/co0693913/2012/The-Survivalist-2015-screenplay-by-Stephen-Fingleton.pdf) this is explained in a little more detail. In short he *wants* maggots in the wound as they'll [debride the wound and eat the infected tissue and leave the healthy tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggot_therapy). It follows that covering himself will prevent birds and mice from getting to the (desired) maggots.

> EXT. STREAM - DAY
> Survivalist pulls open the gauze to inspect the wound. Arching his
> head, he sees a trail of green pus. Not good, in a world without
> antibiotics. He closes his eyes.
>
> EXT. THE HEAPS - DAY
> Survivalist trudges to the stinking, buzzing
> compost heaps. Flies flicker around his face. He lies on the ground,
> quite still, and opens up the gauze, exposing the wound. After some
> time, flies curl and land around the open flesh. He watches them begin
> to nestle around the exposed, festering wound.
>
> INT. CABIN, MAIN ROOM - NIGHT
> The three, eating dinner. Two armed. Survivalist, gaunt and pale.
>
> INT. CABIN, MAIN ROOM - NIGHT (LATER)
> Resting on the bed, Survivalist
> inspects his wound with his small mirror. Tiny MAGGOTS wriggle and
> curl inside. They feast on the infected tissue. Milja watches from the
> open door of the seed room.
>
> **SURVIVALIST:** *I’m sick.*
>
> INT. CABIN, MAIN ROOM - NIGHT
> Survivalist lies in bed, two mouldy
> cushions stacked up against his back. Milja washes the maggots from
> his wound and collects the detritus in a bowl. The infested tissue has
> been eaten away, but he has contracted fever. His skin is deathly
> pale.